# Guidlines not aligned with pixels in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

My guidelines are not correctly aligned with the pixels in my image (see image below). How can I correctly align them?

[image]

I am using Adobe Photoshop CS6.

Comment: Hi web2, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Have the "snap" option selected
2. Select the area which you want it's edges you want to mark with guides **or** select the actual object you want it's edges to be marked with guides.
3. Move the guides to the selection - and the guides should snap to the selection, and the selections are always in pixels

[image]